# Concatenate number and symbol

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to concatenate a number with a symbol in an MS Access textbox.

The field is a number (ie 44), and a symbol (ie °).

I have tried several different ways:

```
=[myNumber] & " °"
```

gives a #Type error

```
=myNumber & " °"
```

also results in a #Type error

```
=[myNumber] & [°]
```

results in a #Name error

Comment: =[myNumber] & " °" should work if you are putting it in the controlsource of the textbox. Unless the name of the textbox is the same as the field name. If that is the case, change the name of the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=[myNumber] & " °"
```

works for me in Access 2010.

You can try to explicitely convert it into a string (and check for NULL, because CStr() doesn't like NULL):

```
=CStr(Nz([myNumber], "")) & " °"
```

Comment: I am using 2013.  Not sure if that makes any difference.  I tried your second formula, and it gives me a #Size! error.  I've never seen that, any ideas?

Comment: @user2796515: What datatype is `myNumber`, and what value does it have? It doesn't sound like it is 44.

Comment: Sorry, it is a number field that can contain a null value.  When first opening the form it is null - I should have mentioned that - sorry

Comment: @user2796515: NULL should be covered by the Nz() function - it should return "" and the textbox should be " °".

Comment: That is what I figured, and that is exactly what I was expecting.  Perhaps it may be best to add a text box with the static symbol.   This will come down to a design decision.  I will mark your answer as correct.  Not sure why I get the size error still though.  Thanks!